# Android's webview.postUrl in Flutter

Tags: webview, flutter

Is there a webview plugin that allows to post params to a webpage, equivalent to Android's webview.postUrl ?

I want to post parameters in a request body in flutter and that redirects to another webpage which I need to display. I am not able to find any current webview plugin that can do this. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) plugin. It has the `postUrl` method:

`inAppWebViewController.postUrl(String url, Uint8List postData);`

Here is an example:

You could import the `dart:convert` library and encode your POST body string into a `Uint8List` data. To do that you can use, for example, the `utf8.encode()` method:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

...

onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
  var data = "firstname=Foo&lastname=Bar";

  controller.postUrl(
    url: "http://192.168.1.123:8082/test-ajax-post",
    postData: utf8.encode(data));
},
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look.

Comment: @rlecheta: I have a similar requirement, Did it work for you? or did you find another solution?

Comment: Yes, I used the flutter_inappbrowser, since the Google plugin doesn't have this postUrl method.

Comment: How can I use Uint8List to send formdata in post method?

Comment: @rlecheta can i have any sample code how to use this one. Thanks

Comment: @lorenzo It replace `+' with space while doing Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode("username=Foo&password=Bar+//ede+")), Can you please help how I can avoid this? I want to send data in form